# Making an X picture in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, shapes

I'm trying to practice how to make simple shapes and am having trouble making this specific shape:

```
        X   X
         X X  
          X 
         X X
        X   X
```

I want to ask the user to enter a size and then, based on the size, it will make a shape in with those dimensions (the above shape is what would be printed if the user input 5). I was able to make a square using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter the size of your shape: ");
    size = scan.nextInt();
```

That will get the size that the user wants. Then in order to draw the rectangle shape, I used this:

```
static void squareShape(int size){
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < size; j++){
            System.out.print("X");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me with drawing the X it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: But what did you use to *try* to make the X; that's what's important for your question.

Comment: Think a little bit, and figure out what values of `i` and `j` would cause you to print an `X` character.  You might want to think about the two diagonals separately.  Try it for a few different sizes.  You should be able to spot a pattern.  Then you can write a double loop that prints out `X` for certain values of `i` and `j`, and prints a space character for all other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing spaces with dots to make it more obvious:

```
X.....X
.X...X
..X.X
...X
..X.X
.X...X
X.....X
```

What you need to do is basically figure out, for each line, how many spaces to print before the first and second X (though there's no second `X` on the center line). To simplify things for now, let's assume the height is always odd.

You can see that the first space-count follows the pattern `{0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0}` with the `3` being half of the height `7`, rounded down. This lends itself to a simple loop counting up to near the midpoint, doing the midpoint itself, then counting down again:

```
for firstSpaces = 0 to height/2 - 1 inclusive
    output firstSpaces spaces, an X and a newline

output height/2 spaces, an X and a newline

for firstSpaces = height/2 - 1 to 0 inclusive
    output firstSpaces spaces, an X and a newline
```

The second space count is a similar `{5, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 5}` where the starting point is `height - 2` and it decreases by two each time in the first loop, increasing by two each time through the second loop. This basically modifies the pseudo-code as follows:

```
secondSpaces = height - 2
for firstSpaces = 0 to height/2 - 1 inclusive
    output firstSpaces spaces and an X
    output secondSpaces spaces, an X and a newline
    subtract 2 from secondSpaces

output height/2 spaces, an X and a newline

for firstSpaces = height/2 - 1 to 0 inclusive
    add 2 to secondSpaces
    output firstSpaces spaces and an X
    output secondSpaces spaces, an X and a newline
```

Putting together a proof of concept in Python 3 (the ultimate pseudo-code language):

```
def x(sz):
    secondSpaces = sz - 2
    for firstSpaces in range(sz//2):
        print(' ' * firstSpaces,end='X')
        print(' ' * secondSpaces,end='X\n')
        secondSpaces -= 2

    print(' ' * (sz//2),end='X\n')

    for firstSpaces in range(sz//2 - 1, -1, -1):
        secondSpaces += 2
        print(' ' * firstSpaces,end='X')
        print(' ' * secondSpaces,end='X\n')

    print()

x(3)
x(5)
x(7)
x(15)
```

shows that the logic is sound:

```
X X
 X
X X

X   X
 X X
  X
 X X
X   X

X     X
 X   X
  X X
   X
  X X
 X   X
X     X

X             X
 X           X
  X         X
   X       X
    X     X
     X   X
      X X
       X
      X X
     X   X
    X     X
   X       X
  X         X
 X           X
X             X
```

Now you just have to write similar code in your language of choice and (possibly) cater for non-odd heights as well, if desired.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed response! It definitely makes more sense after I read your comment. I think I'll be able to complete this once I give it a second go. Thanks!